# How can I have a Solr auto update an index from a JSON file

Tags: json, solr

I want to have Solr watch and auto update an index from a JSON file. Is this doable and if so what is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Solr doesn't have any mechanism for watching for a file to change. You can however work around this - depending on your OS - to have a small program watch the file or directory for a change, and then submit the JSON document to Solr.

See [How to execute a command whenever a file changes](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes) on Superuser.